# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in cryptoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs, tripledes

I am trying to encrypt data in cryptoJS in nodeJS but it throws this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code snippet

```
var crypto1 = require("crypto-js");

var key = new ArrayBuffer(16)

key = [
  43,
  57,
  97,
  -68,
  -63,
  -61,
  -40,
  9,
  50,
  87,
  -104,
  101,
  63,
  34,
  -78,
  60,
];

const tripledes = require("crypto-js/tripledes")
const init = tripledes.encrypt

let ciphertext = init('12345586', key).toString();

console.log(base64.encode(ciphertext));
```

Comment: if you fixed your problem, plz share your solution. if my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `key` in `tripledes.encrypt(text, key)` must be string

```
var crypto1 = require("crypto-js");

var key = new ArrayBuffer(16)

key = [
  43,
  57,
  97,
  -68,
  -63,
  -61,
  -40,
  9,
  50,
  87,
  -104,
  101,
  63,
  34,
  -78,
  60,
];

const tripledes = require("crypto-js/tripledes")
const init = tripledes.encrypt


// let ciphertext = init('12345586', key <--- ).toString();
let ciphertext = init('12345586', key.toString()).toString();

console.log(ciphertext);
```